# Top 3 most flights delayed (>1h) in percentage by airline code (list)

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get top 3 most delayed companies by percantage (by more than an hour).

Here is a table example (ARR_DELAY is in minutes, also - means that they arrived early):

| AIRLINE_CODE | ARR_DELAY |
| --- | --- |
| DL | -6 |
| DL | 123 |
| DL | -47 |
| DL | 32 |

There are unique airline codes too, but they repet a lot (because it happens daily)
"AIRLINE_CODE", "9E", "AA", "AS", "B6", "DL"

```
Here is a code I have so far:
SELECT "ninteen_Flights"."AIRLINE_CODE",
100.0 * "ninteen_Flights"."ARR_DELAY" / sum("ninteen_Flights"."ARR_DELAY") OVER (PARTITION BY "ninteen_Flights"."AIRLINE_CODE") AS avg
FROM "ninteen_Flights"
GROUP BY "ninteen_Flights"."AIRLINE_CODE"
```

I know that code is wrong. However, I have no idea how to get result that i need...

I am trying to get top 3 most delayed companies by percantage (by more than an hour).

Answer (score 2):

For this you do not need to use a window query, you can do this with a simple `GROUP BY`. By the term "*most delayed*" this often implies that we are asking about the *frequency* of the delay and not the specific cumulative or average delay, if they wanted that they would have asked. The final support to this line of thinking is the additional criteria: *by more than an hour*.

I suspect that what you are really asking for is:
**the top 3 airlines with the most frequently delayed flights, where the delay is more than 1 hour.**

For this we won't actually calculate the total cumulative delay or anything like that, we just want the number of flights, to do that we can use a `CASE` statement to project the data into 2 sets of columns we can compare:

> **NOTE:** In other RDBMS like SQL Server, we can use some tricks with `NULL` values to simplify this type of logic, but in [PostgreSQL `COUNT()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-count-function/) counts *all* rows, including `NULL`s. So instead of using `NULL` we will use `SUM()` with 1s and 0s

*While it is not necessary to do so, we can express this as a percentage*

```
SELECT "ninteen_Flights"."AIRLINE_CODE",
    100.0 * 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN "ninteen_Flights"."ARR_DELAY" > 60 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) / 
    COUNT(*) AS "AVG_DELAYED"
FROM "ninteen_Flights"
GROUP BY "ninteen_Flights"."AIRLINE_CODE"
ORDER BY "AVG_DELAYED" DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8f4e4/5